# Internet Connection slow with Linux

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet, net

I have a problem with my new internet connection. This is a symmetric 500Mbs connection but i only get 50M in my linux computer (fedora 30). In windows I get 500Mb for up and down with other computer. I know that the problem is in my ethernet connection in linux because my speed in ethernet card is 100Mb. I don't know why.

This is the ethernet card values (it supports 1Gb)

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: No
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: off
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                       drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: yes
```

I tried with ethtool but when I try to change to 1000Mb/s with

```
$ sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 speed 1000 duplex full

Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: no
```

but I get no link connection

If I try to up the enp3s0 the 1000Mb speed disappears and I get 100M again

```
$ sudo ifup enp3s0 

$ 
Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
enp3s0: 100 Mbit, half duplex, link ok
$
```

I don't know what else to try.

Thanks

Comment: Considering you say it's working fine in an other OS (is it connected exactly the same or differently?), this looks like a driver problem. Not sure how it could be helped here on UL, but anyway there's one missing information: the card brand and chipset model.

Comment: Also it's strange that autonegociation is off. Did you try keeping it on? AFAIK 1000mbps requires autoneg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation "is mandatory for 1000BASE-T gigabit Ethernet over twisted pair."

Comment: 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)

Comment: Try with `ethtool -s enp3s0 autoneg on`

Comment: To realpclaudio, Sorry but I can't point your comment. If you put an answer I will mark how the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with realpclaudio answer.

```
$ sudo ethtool -s enp3s0 autoneg on

Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

Thanks.